# How to calculate $(n+1)$'th derivative of $\prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-a_i)$ with constants $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Letting $f(x):=\prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-a_i)$, with a real variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, I want to calculate the $(n+1)$'th derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. $f(x)$ is a product of $(n+1)$ linear functions in $x$, each of which are $(n+1)$ times differentiable. In this regard I was thinking of maybe applying the general leibniz rule to calculate the derivative, but I don't fully understand the basis of it yet. Another approach that comes to mind is a calculation involving induction on $n$. What would be a desirable approach?

Comment: The expression is polynomial of degree n so the n+1th derivative is zero

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$ !

Answer (score 2):

$\prod_{i=0}^n (x-a_i)$ is a polynomial of degree exactly $n+1$, so the derivative is $(n+1)!$ times the leading coefficient (1, in your case).

So the answer is $(n+1)!$

Answer (score 1):

It may be more clear to write it out. By definition, $$\prod_{i=0}^n (x - a_i) = (x-a_0)(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n).$$ We can expand the right hand side to get $x^{n+1} -(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n)x^{n} + \dots + a_0a_1a_2\cdots a_n.$ Taking the derivative, it is clear that we have $(n+1)!.$